# Como agrego "minas" al rededor de una coordenada, en un buscaminas

Tags: python, string, lista, bucle-for, while

Tengo esta Matriz que representa un tablero de buscaminas, pero tengo un problema no se como añadir los "1", "2","3", etc que representan las casillas que te indican que hay una mina cerca
(Ej: si hay un 8 es poque hay una mina, y las 8 casillas alrededor del 8 deben marcar minimo un "1", ya que 8 simboliza una mina)

```
tablero = [["A",0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
       ["B",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
       ["C",8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["D",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
       ["E",0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["F",0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["G",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["H",0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["I",0,8,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
       ["J",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["K",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0,0],
       ["L",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["M",0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["N",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["O",0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

for fila in range(1,len(tablero)):
for columna in range(1,len(tablero[i])):
    if tablero[fila][columna]>=10:
        #si la mina esta en posicion 6 no se puede sumar una posicion
        #si la mina esta en posicion 1 no se puede restar una posicion
        if columna>1 and fila>1 and columna<6 and fila <6:
            tablero[fila-1][columna-1]+=1
            tablero[fila-1][columna]+=1
            tablero[fila-1][columna+1]+=1
            tablero[fila][columna-1]+=1
            tablero[fila][columna+1]+=1
            tablero[fila+1][columna-1]+=1
            tablero[fila+1][columna]+=1
            tablero[fila+1][columna+1]+=1
```

Empece haciendo este código pero la verdad no funciona porque no se hacia donde estoy llendo y es muy extenso, si existiera alguna forma de optimizarlo, o escribir otro codigo seria ideal recibir su ayuda.
De ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución propuesta consta de tres partes:

Primero necesitamos una función `valor_celda`, que recupera el valor de una celda dado (fila, columna). Si la celda no existe, retorna cero. Esta función se encarga del problema de ver si una celda existe o no.

Segundo. Con esa función podemos construir la función `cuenta_minas`, que cuenta las minas alrededor de una fila, columna.

Tercero, recorremos el tablero contando las minas en alrededor de cada celda.

El principio se llama "dividir para reinar"

El código es:

```
tablero = [["A",0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
       ["B",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
       ["C",8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["D",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
       ["E",0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["F",0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["G",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["H",0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["I",0,8,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
       ["J",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["K",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0,0],
       ["L",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["M",0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["N",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0],
       ["O",0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

n_filas = len(tablero)
n_columnas = len(tablero[0])

def valor_celda(fila, columna):
    """ Recupera el valor de la celda en fila, columna.
        Si la celda no existe, retorna cero.
    """
    valor = 0
    if fila >= 0 and fila < n_filas:
        if columna > 0 and columna < n_columnas:
            valor = tablero[fila][columna]
    return valor

def cuenta_minas(fila, columna):
    """ Cuenta las minas alrededor de fila, columna.
        Actualiza la cuenta directamente en el tablero.
    """
    if tablero[fila][columna] == 0:
        for row in range(fila - 1, fila + 2):
            for col in range(columna - 1, columna + 2):
                if valor_celda(row, col) == 8:
                    tablero[fila][columna] += 1 

#  Recorrer el tablero contando las minas.
for fila in range(n_filas):
    for columna in range(1, n_columnas):
         cuenta_minas(fila, columna)

for fila in tablero:
    print(fila)
```

Que produce:

```
['A', 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0]
['B', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0]
['C', 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
['D', 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0]
['E', 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
['F', 0, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['G', 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['H', 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
['I', 1, 8, 2, 8, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0]
['J', 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
['K', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 0, 0]
['L', 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
['M', 0, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['N', 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['O', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, lo revisare, soy nuevo en esto de la programacion.